# Selecting edges based on both edge's data and target's data

Tags: cytoscape.js

I would like a selector for edges matching

```
edge[type="blocker"]
```

that have a target matching

```
node[status="complete"]
```

In other words, is there a valid way of expressing the following:

```
cytoscape({
   ...
   style: [
      ...
      {
         selector: '( node -> node[status="complete"] )[type="blocker"]',
         style: {
            display: 'none',
         },
      },
      ...
   ],
   ...
})
```

I don't see a way of doing this in the [documentation](http://js.cytoscape.org/index.html#selectors).

Obviously, I could copy the target's data into the node's data and use the following:

```
edge[type="blocker"][target_status="complete"]
```

But duplicating the data goes against my every instinct as a software developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no selector that will help.

---

However, it is possible to avoid having to manually update two elements when data changes.

Style sheet value functions are called every time a matching element's data changes. In one those function, one could therefore update the data of incoming edges every time the node's data is updated, keeping the data of the two in sync automatically.

```
var push_status = function(node) {
   node.incomers('edge').forEach( edge => edge.data('target_status', node.data('status')) );
   node.outgoers('edge').forEach( edge => edge.data('source_status', node.data('status')) );
};

cytoscape({
   ...
   style: [
      ...
      {
         selector: 'node',
         style: {
            label: node => { push_status(node); return node.data('id'); },
         },
      },
      {
         selector: 'edge[type="blocker"][target_status="complete"]',
         style: {
            display: 'none',
         },
      },
      ...
   ],
   ...
})
```

This would qualify as a hack, but it works perfectly. Updating the node's data updates the edge's data, which causes the style to be applied or unapplied as appropriate.

---

Be wary of creating an infinite loop! In particular, modifying the data of a node's parent will trigger a calculation of the node's style. This problem can be avoided by replacing

```
ele.data('key', val)
```

with

```
// Making changes to a element's data triggers a style recalculation.
// This avoids needlessly triggering the style recalculation.
var set_data = function(node, key, new_val) {
   let old_val = node.data(key);
   if (new_val != old_val)
       node.data(key, new_val);
};

set_data(ele, 'key', val)
```

Comment: Another way is to update edge style on node data change event without copying the data.

Comment: @user3140972, That's no different than the problem the OP is trying to avoid: You still need to manually keep two things in sync. If you change the data, you also need to change the edge's classes. It's not the end of the world, but the question is about avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide function to filter method:

```
cy.edges().filter(function(ele) {
    return ele.data('type') == 'blocker' &&
        ele.target().data('status') == 'complete';
})
```

Comment: I requested a selector because this is to be used in a style sheet, but I don't think what you provided can be used for that purpose. I have extended the example in the question to provide clarification.

Comment: @ikegami the value of style properties can be functions. A workaround: select edges which are `blocker` with selector, then set the value of `display` to a function which returns `none` if the target is complete.

Comment: I was just trying that: `display: ele => ele.target().data('status') == 'complete' ? 'none' : 'element'`. Unfortunately (but understandably), the value isn't recalculated when the *target*'s data is updated. (The value is only recalculated when the *edge*'s data is updated.)

Comment: Oh, that gives me a nasty idea: A function in the target's style sheet that modifies the edge's data or classes as a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

How about this
**EDIT:**

```
var selectedEdges = cy.nodes("[status= 'complete']").connectedEdges("[type = 'blocker']);
var selectedEdges.addClass('specialSnowflake')
```

And in your stylesheet, just define:

```
{
   "selector": "edge.specialSnowflake",
   "style": { 
      "display": "none"
   }
}
```

Comment: That's no different that copying that data: You still need to keep two things in sync. If you change the data, you also need to change the edge's classes. It's not the end of the world, but the question is about avoid that.

Comment: Frankly, I don't think that these selectors are capable of doing this task ... perhaps there is in fact a better solution to this, but the selector checks the classes set for the elements in cytoscape, I can't think about a solution w/o using a class to filter this...

Answer (score 0):

If a selector does not suffice, then you could (1) suggest a new feature to enhance the edge `->` selector and perhaps even make a PR for it or (2) use a function on the style property instead.

E.g. for (2):

```
{ selector: 'edge', style: { display: edgeIsDisplayed } }
```

where the function can be anything, like `edgeIsDisplayed(edge) => edge.data('foo') === 'bar' && edge.target().hasClass('baz')`

See http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/mappers

Comment: The problem with this is explained in detail in my answer: the function isn't actually called when `edge.target().hasClass('baz')` is changed. It's only called when `edge.data()` (and possibly `edge.classes()`) is changed

Comment: That's right.  Mappers don't get updated on changes to connected nodes for performance reasons.  There's a private function for updating mappers, but it's currently not documented.  That may need to be made public for usecases like this.